# rsync treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir only if it's not modified otherwise it will copy the dir

Tags: linux, rsync, symlink

I want to keep the soft link if there is no diff between the files, and if there is a difference I want to copy the directory.
I am using

```
rsync -rk src dis
```

in src I have directory:`dir1` that have `file1` and `file2`, and in `dis` I have `dir1->/home/dir1` (soft link) in `/home/dir1/` there is only `file1`
when I run the `rsync -rk src dis`, `file2` is copied to `/home/dir1/`
I don't want files to be copied to `/home/dir1/` I want to remove the soft link and copy `src/dir1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with a single invocation of `rsync`. I would approach this by using `rsync` to test whether any files have changed, and if so then perform the copy.

Example

```
# Setup
mkdir /tmp/710162
cd /tmp/710162

mkdir -p src/dir1 dis home/dir1
date >src/dir1/file1
cp -p src/dir1/file1 home/dir1
ln -s /tmp/710162/home/dir1 dis/dir1
```

Code

```
if rsync --dry-run --keep-dirlinks -ai src/ dis | grep -q '^[^.]'
then
    echo "Changes found"
    rsync -ai src/ dis
fi
```

Result of running immediately after setup: nothing (i.e. the symlink remains intact and files are unchanged)

```
who >src/dir1/file2
```

Result of running after a new file is added:

```
Changes found
.d..t...... ./
cd+++++++++ dir1/
>f+++++++++ dir1/file1
>f+++++++++ dir1/file2
```

At this point the symlink is removed and copies of the source files are placed into a newly created `dir1` directory.

(There may appear to be a race condition between the `rsync` used for the conditional test and the one for performing the copy, but it's not relevant here.)